# A layman's explanation for "Everything is a file" — what differs from Windows?

Tags: files, windows, architecture, unix-philosophy

I know that "Everything is a file" means that even devices have their filename and path in Unix and Unix-like systems, and that this allows for common tools to be used on a variety of resources regardless of their nature. But I can't contrast that to Windows, the only other OS I have worked with. I have read some articles about the concept, but I think they are somewhat uneasy to grasp for non-developers. A layman's explanation is what people need!

For example, when I want to copy a file to CF card that is attached to a card reader, I will use something like

```
zcat name_of_file > /dev/sdb
```

In Windows, I think the card reader will appear as a driver, and we will do something similar, I think. So, how does the "Everything is a file" philosophy make a difference here?

Comment: It sounds you like you already understand the layman's explanation.

Comment: Not entirely, I want to understand the benefit of it by comparing to MS Windows for example. And I didn't get the part about the inter-process communication in it.

Comment: Judging by that example, you also don't quite understand how filesystems work. Unless `name_of_file` happens to be a proper filesystem image, you just wrecked that CF card...

Comment: @Shadur Yes, it is a file system image, see http://wiki.ipfire.org/en/installation/start#installation_on_a_alix-board

Answer (score 140, accepted):

"Everything is a file" is a bit glib. "Everything appears somewhere in the [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system)" is closer to the mark, and even then, it's more an ideal than a law of system design.

For example, [Unix domain sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) are not files, but they do appear in the file system. You can `ls -l` a domain socket to display its attributes, modify its access control via `chmod`, and on some Unix type systems (e.g. macOS, but not Linux) you can even `cat` data to/from one.

But, even though regular [TCP/IP network sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) are created and manipulated with the same [BSD sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bsd_sockets) system calls as Unix domain sockets, TCP/IP sockets do *not* show up in the file system,¹ even though there is no especially good reason that this should be true.

Another example of non-file objects appearing in the file system is [Linux's `/proc` file system](https://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt). This feature exposes a great amount of detail about the kernel's run-time operation to [user space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space), mostly as virtual plain text files. Many `/proc` entries are read-only, but a lot of `/proc` is also writeable, so you can change the way the system runs using any program that can modify a file. Alas, here again we have a nonideality: BSD Unixes [run without `/proc` by default](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/articles/linux-users/#procfs), and the System V Unixes expose a lot less via `/proc` than Linux does.

> I can't contrast that to MS Windows

First, much of the sentiment you can find online and in books about Unix being all about file I/O and Windows being "broken" in this regard is obsolete. [Windows NT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_nt) fixed a lot of this.

Modern versions of Windows have a unified I/O system, just like Unix, so you can read network data from a TCP/IP socket via [`ReadFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) rather than the Windows Sockets specific API [`WSARecv()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsarecv), if you want to. This exactly parallels the [Unix Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy), where you can read from a network socket with either the generic [`read(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) Unix system call or the sockets-specific [`recv(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) call.²

Nevertheless, Windows still fails to take this concept to the same level as Unix, even here in 2021. There are many areas of the Windows architecture that cannot be accessed through the file system, or that can't be viewed as file-like. Some examples:

1. **Drivers.**

   Windows' driver subsystem is easily as rich and powerful as Unix's, but to write programs to manipulate drivers, you generally have to use the [Windows Driver Kit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/), which means writing C or .NET code.

   On Unix type OSes, you can do a lot to drivers from the command line. You've almost certainly already done this, if only by redirecting unwanted output to `/dev/null`.³
2. **Inter-program communication.**

   Windows programs don't communicate easily with each other as Unix command line programs do, via text streams and pipes. Unix GUIs are often either built on top of command line programs or export a text command interface, so the same simple text-based communication mechanisms work with GUI programs, too.
3. **The registry.**

   Unix has no direct equivalent of the Windows registry. The same information is scattered through the file system, largely in `/etc`, `/proc` and `/sys`.

If you don't see that drivers, pipes, and Unix's answer to the Windows registry have anything to do with "everything is a file," read on.

> How does the "Everything is a file" philosophy make a difference here?

I will explain that by expanding on my three points above, in detail.

**Long answer, part 1: Drives vs Device Files**

Let's say your CF card reader appears as `E:` under Windows and `/dev/sdc` under Linux. What practical difference does it make?

It is not just a minor syntax difference.

On Linux, I can say `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc` to overwrite the contents of `/dev/sdc` with zeroes.

Think about what that means for a second. Here I have a normal user space program ([`dd(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dd)) that I asked to read data in from a virtual device (`/dev/zero`) and write what it read out to a real physical device (`/dev/sdc`) via the unified Unix file system. `dd` doesn't know it is reading from and writing to special devices. It will work on regular files just as well, or on a mix of devices and files, as we will see below.

There is no easy way to zero the `E:` drive on Windows because Windows makes a distinction between files and drives, so you cannot use the same commands to manipulate them. The closest you can get is to do a disk format without the Quick Format option, which zeroes *most* of the drive contents, but then writes a new file system on top of it. What if I don't *want* a new file system? What if I really do want the disk to be filled with nothing but zeroes?

Let's be generous and accept this requirement to put a fresh new file system on `E:`. To do that in a program on Windows, I have to call a special formatting API.⁴ On Linux, you don't need to write a program to access the OS's "format disk" functionality: you just run the appropriate user space program for the file system type you want to create, whether that's [`mkfs.ext4`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext4), [`mkfs.xfs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.xfs), or what have you. These programs will write a file system onto whatever file or `/dev` node you pass.

Because `mkfs` type programs on Unixy systems don't make artificial distinctions between devices and normal files, I can create an [ext4 file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) inside a normal file on my Linux box:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=myfs bs=1k count=1k
$ mkfs.ext4 -F myfs
```

That creates a 1 MiB disk image called `myfs` in the current directory. I can then mount it as if it were any other external file system:

```
$ mkdir mountpoint
$ sudo mount -o loop myfs mountpoint
$ grep $USER /etc/passwd > mountpoint/my-passwd-entry
$ sudo umount mountpoint
```

Now I have an ext4 disk image with a file called `my-passwd-entry` in it which contains my user's `/etc/passwd` entry.

If I want, I can blast that image onto my CF card:

```
$ sudo dd if=myfs of=/dev/sdc1
```

Or, I can pack that disk image up, mail it to you, and let you write it to a medium of *your* choosing, such as a USB memory stick:

```
$ gzip myfs
$ echo "Here's the disk image I promised to send you." | 
  mutt -a myfs.gz -s "Password file disk image" \
      you@example.com
```

All of this is possible on Linux⁵ because there is no artificial distinction between files, file systems, and devices. Many things on Unix systems either *are* files, or are accessed through the file system so they *look like* files, or in some other way look sufficiently file-like that they can be treated as such.

Windows' concept of the file system is a hodgepodge; it makes distinctions between directories, drives, and network resources. There are three different syntaxes, all blended together in Windows: the Unix-like `..\FOO\BAR` path system, drive letters like `C:`, and UNC paths like `\\SERVER\PATH\FILE.TXT`. This is because it's an accretion of ideas from Unix, [CP/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp/m), [MS-DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ms-dos), and [LAN Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAN_Manager) rather than a single coherent design. It is why there are [so many illegal characters in Windows file names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations).

Unix has a unified file system, with everything accessed by a single common scheme. To a program running on a Linux box, there is no functional difference between `/etc/passwd`, `/media/CF_CARD/etc/passwd`, and `/mnt/server/etc/passwd`. Local files, external media, and network shares all get treated the same way.⁶

Windows can achieve similar ends to my disk image example above, but you have to use special programs written by uncommonly talented programmers. This is why there are [so many "virtual DVD" type programs on Windows](https://howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/mount-an-iso-image-in-windows-vista/). The lack of a core OS feature has created an artificial market for programs to fill the gap, which means you have a bunch of people competing to create the best virtual DVD type program. We don't need such programs on *ix systems, because we can just mount an ISO disk image using a [loop device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device).

The same goes for other tools like [disk wiping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_wipe) programs, which we also don't need on Unix systems. Want your CF card's contents irretrievably scrambled instead of just zeroed? Okay, use [`/dev/random`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) as the data source instead of `/dev/zero`:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/sdc
```

On Linux, we don't keep reinventing such wheels because the core OS features not only work well enough, they work so well they're used pervasively. [One of several ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_startup_process) for booting a Linux box involves a virtual disk image created using techniques like I show above.

I feel it's only fair to point out that if Unix had integrated TCP/IP I/O into the file system from the start, we wouldn't have the `netcat` vs `socat` vs `ncat` vs `nc` [mess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#Ports_and_reimplementations), the cause of which was the same design weakness that led to the disk imaging and wiping tool proliferation on Windows: lack of an acceptable OS facility.

**Long Answer, part 2: Pipes as Virtual Files**

Despite its roots in MS-DOS, Windows never has had a rich command line tradition.

This is not to say that Windows doesn't *have* a command line, or that it lacks many command line programs. Windows even has a very powerful command shell these days, appropriately called [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powershell).

Yet, there are knock-on effects of this lack of a command-line tradition. You get tools like [`DISKPART`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart) which is almost unknown in the Windows world, because most people do disk partitioning and such through the Computer Management MMC snap-in. Then when you do need to script the creation of partitions, you find that `DISKPART` wasn't really made to be driven by another program. Yes, you can write a series of commands into a script file and run it via `DISKPART /S scriptfile`, but it's all-or-nothing. What you *really* want in such a situation is something more like [GNU `parted`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/parted), which will accept single commands like `parted /dev/sdb mklabel gpt`. That allows your script to do error handling on a step-by-step basis.

What does all this have to do with "everything is a file"? Easy: [pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) make command line program I/O into "files," of a sort. Pipes are unidirectional [streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_%28computing%29), not [random-access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access) like a regular disk file, but in many cases the difference is of no consequence. The important thing is that you can attach two independently developed programs and make them communicate via simple text. In that sense, any two programs designed with the [Unix Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) in mind can communicate.

In those cases where you really do need a file, it is easy to turn program output into a file:

```
$ some-program --some --args > myfile
$ vi myfile
```

But why write the output to a temporary file when the "everything is a file" philosophy gives you a better way? If all you want to do is read the output of that command into a `vi` editor buffer, you can do that directly from the `vi` "normal" mode:

```
:r !some-program --some --args
```

That inserts that program's output into the active editor buffer at the current cursor position. Under the hood, `vi` is using pipes to connect the output of the program to a bit of code that uses the same OS calls it would use to read from a file instead. I wouldn't be surprised if the two cases of `:r` — that is, with and without the `!` — both used the same generic data reading loop in all common implementations of `vi`. I can't think of a good reason not to.

This isn't a recent feature of `vi`, either; it goes clear back to the [ancient](https://gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html) [`ed(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ed) text editor.

This powerful idea pops up over and over in Unix.

For a second example of this, recall my `mutt` email command above. The only reason I had to write that as two separate commands is that I wanted the temporary file to be named `*.gz` so that the email attachment would be correctly named. If I didn't care about the file's name, I could have used [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_06) to avoid creating the temporary file:

```
$ echo "Here's the disk image I promised to send you." | 
  mutt -a <(gzip -c myfs) -s "Password file disk image" \
      you@example.com
```

That turns the output of `gzip -c` into a FIFO (which is file-like) or a `/dev/fd` object (which is file-like).⁷

For yet a third way this powerful idea appears in Unix, consider [`gdb`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gdb) on Linux systems. This is the debugger used for any software written in C and C++. Programmers coming to Unix from other systems look at `gdb` and almost invariably gripe, "Yuck, it's so primitive!" Then they go searching for a GUI debugger, find one of several that exist, and happily continue their work…often never realizing that the GUI just runs `gdb` underneath, providing a pretty shell on top of it. There aren't competing low-level debuggers on most Unix systems because there is no need for programs to compete at that level. All we need is one good low-level tool that we can all base our high-level tools on, if that low-level tool communicates easily via pipes.

This means we now have a documented debugger interface which would allow drop-in replacement of `gdb`. It's unfortunate that the primary competitor to `gdb` [didn't take this low-friction path](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html), but that quibble aside, `lldb` is just as scriptable as `gdb`.

To pull the same thing off on a Windows box, the creators of the replaceable tool would have had to define some kind of formal plugin or automation API. That means it doesn't happen except for the very most popular programs, because it's a lot of work to build both a normal command line user interface and a complete programming API.

This magic happens through the grace of pervasive text-based [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Although Windows' kernel [has Unix-style anonymous pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-createpipe), it's rare to see normal user programs use them for [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) outside of a command shell, because Windows lacks this tradition of creating all core services in a command line version first, then building the GUI on top of it separately. This leads to being unable to do some things without the GUI, which is one reason why there are so many [remote desktop systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software) for Windows, as compared to Linux. This is doubtless part of the reason why Linux is the operating system of the cloud, where everything's done by remote management. Command line interfaces are easier to automate than GUIs in large part because "everything is a file."

Consider SSH. You may ask, how does it work? SSH connects a network socket (which is file-like) to a [pseudo tty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal) at `/dev/pty*` (which is file-like). Now your remote system is connected to your local one through a connection that so seamlessly matches the Unix Way that [you can pipe data through the SSH connection](https://cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-tar-command-through-network-over-ssh-session/), if you need to.

Are you getting an idea of just how powerful this concept is now?

A piped text stream is indistinguishable from a file from a program's perspective, except that it's unidirectional. A program reads from a pipe the same way it reads from a file: through a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor). FDs are absolutely core to Unix; the fact that files, pipes, and network sockets all use the same abstraction for I/O on both should tell you something.

The Windows world, lacking this tradition of simple text communications, makes do with heavyweight [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) interfaces via [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) or [.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework). If you need to automate such a program, you must also write a COM or .NET program. This is a fair bit more difficult than setting up a pipe on a Unix box.

Windows programs lacking these complicated programming APIs can only communicate through impoverished interfaces like the clipboard or File/Save followed by File/Open.

**Long Answer, part 3: The Registry vs Configuration Files**

The practical difference between the Windows registry and the Unix Way of system configuration also illustrates the benefits of the "everything is a file" philosophy.

On Unix type systems, I can look at system configuration information from the command line merely by examining files. I can change system behavior by modifying those same files. For the most part, these configuration files are just plain text files, which means I can use any tool on Unix to manipulate them that can work with plain text files.

[Scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_(computing)) the registry is not nearly so easy on Windows.

The easiest method is to make your changes through the Registry Editor GUI on one machine, then [blindly apply those changes to other machines with `regedit` via `*.reg` files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-add-modify-or-delete-registry-subkeys-and-values-by-using-a-reg-file-9c7f37cf-a5e9-e1cd-c4fa-2a26218a1a23). That isn't really "scripting," since it doesn't let you do anything conditionally: it's all or nothing.

If your registry changes need any amount of logic, the next easiest option is to learn [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powershell), which amounts to learning .NET system programming. It would be like if Unix only had Perl, and you had to do all *ad hoc* system administration through it. Now, I'm a Perl fan, but not everyone is. Unix lets you use any tool you happen to like, as long as it can manipulate plain text files.

---

**Footnotes:**

1. [Plan 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Bell_Labs) fixed this design misstep, exposing network I/O via [the `/net` virtual file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Bell_Labs#/net).

   Bash has [`/dev/tcp`](https://thesmithfam.org/blog/2006/05/23/bash-socket-programming-with-devtcp-2/) that allows network I/O via regular file system functions. Since it is a Bash feature, rather a kernel feature, it isn't visible outside of Bash or on [systems that don't use Bash at all](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145524/138). This shows, by counterexample, why it is such a good idea to make all data resources visible through the file system.
2. By "modern Windows," I mean Windows NT and all of its direct descendants, which includes Windows 2000, all versions of Windows Server, and all desktop-oriented versions of Windows from XP onward. I use the term to exclude the MS-DOS-based versions of Windows, being Windows 95 and its direct descendants, Windows 98 and Windows ME, plus their 16-bit predecessors.

   You can see the distinction by the lack of a unified I/O system in those latter OSes. You cannot pass a TCP/IP socket to `ReadFile()` on Windows 95; you can only pass sockets to the Windows Sockets APIs. See Andrew Schulman's seminal article, [Windows 95: What It's Not](https://web.archive.org/web/20140908084922/http://oreilly.com/centers/windows/brochure/isnot.html) for a deeper dive into this topic.
3. Make no mistake, `/dev/null` is a real kernel device on Unix type systems, not just a special-cased file name, as is the superficially equivalent [`NUL`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) in Windows.

   Although Windows tries to prevent you from creating a `NUL` file, it is possible to bypass this protection [with mere trickery](https://pastebin.com/rTs88KmD), fooling Windows' file name parsing logic. If you try to access that file with `cmd.exe` or Explorer, Windows will refuse to open it, but you can write to it via Cygwin, since it opens files using similar methods to the example program, and you can delete it [via similar trickery](https://superuser.com/q/282194/14927).

   By contrast, Unix will happily let you `rm /dev/null`, as long as you have write access to `/dev`, and let you recreate a new file in its place, all without trickery, because that [dev node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) is just another file. While that dev node is missing, the kernel's null device still exists; it's just inaccessible until you recreate the dev node via [`mknod`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mknod).

   You can even create additional null device dev nodes elsewhere: it doesn't matter if you call it `/home/grandma/Recycle Bin`, as long as it's a dev node for the null device, it will work exactly the same as `/dev/null`.
4. There are actually *two* high-level "format disk" APIs in Windows: [`SHFormatDrive()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shformatdrive) and [`Win32_Volume.Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa394515(v=vs.85)).

   There are two for a very…well…*Windows* sort of reason. The first one asks Windows Explorer to display its normal "Format Disk" dialog box, which means it works on any modern version of Windows, but only while a user is interactively logged in. The other you can call in the background without user input, but it wasn't added to Windows until Windows Server 2003. That's right, core OS behavior was hidden behind a GUI until 2003, in a world where Unix shipped `mkfs` [from day 1](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/1/mkfs).

   The `/etc/mkfs` in my [copy of Unix V5](http://simh.trailing-edge.com/software.html) from 1974 is a 4136 byte statically-linked [PDP-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdp-11) executable. (Unix didn't get dynamic linkage [until the late 1980s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunos), so it's not like there's a big library somewhere else doing all the real work.) Its source code — included in the V5 system image as [`/usr/source/s2/mkfs.c`](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V5/usr/source/s2/mkfs.c) — is an entirely self-contained 457-line C program. There aren't even any `#include` statements!

   This means you can not only examine what `mkfs` does at a high level, you can experiment with it using the same tool set Unix was created with, just like you're [Ken Thompson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Thompson), four decades ago. Try that with Windows. The closest you can come today is to download the [MS-DOS source code](https://computerhistory.org/atchm/microsoft-ms-dos-early-source-code/), first released in *2014*, which you find amounts to just a pile of [assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembler_(computing)) sources. It will only build with obsolete tools you probably won't have on-hand, and in the end you get your very own copy of MS-DOS 2.0, an OS far less powerful than 1974's [Unix V5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_UNIX_Systems), despite its being released nearly a decade later.

   (Why talk about Unix V5? Because it is the earliest complete Unix system still available. Earlier versions are [apparently lost to time](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V4). There was [a project](https://github.com/DoctorWkt/unix-jun72) that pieced together a V1/V2 era Unix, but it appears to be missing `mkfs`, despite the existence of the V1 manual page linked above proving it must have existed somewhere, somewhen. Either those putting this project together couldn't find an extant copy of `mkfs` to include, or I suck at finding files without `find(1)`, which also doesn't exist in that system. `:)`)

   Now, you might be thinking, "Can't I just call `format.com`? Isn't that the same on Windows as calling `mkfs` on Unix?" Alas, no, it isn't the same, for a bunch of reasons:

   - First, `format.com` wasn't designed to be scripted. It prompts you to "press ENTER when ready", which means you need to send an Enter key to its input, or it'll just hang.
   - Then, if you want anything more than a success/failure status code, you have to open its standard output for reading, which is [far more complicated on Windows than it has to be](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output). (On Unix, everything in that linked article can be accomplished with a simple [`popen(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) call.)
   - Having gone through all this complication, the output of `format.com` is harder to parse for computer programs than the output of `mkfs`, being intended primarily for human consumption.
   - If you trace what `format.com` does, you find that it does a bunch of complicated calls to [`DeviceIoControl()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-deviceiocontrol), `ufat.dll`, and such. It is not simply opening a device file and writing a new file system onto that device. This is the sort of design you get from [a company that employs 221000 people worldwide](https://news.microsoft.com/facts-about-microsoft/#EmploymentInfo) and needs to *keep* employing them.

     Contrast what happens when your core OS tools are written by volunteers in their spare time: they come up with expedient, minimal solutions to their problems that pay simplicity dividends to the rest of us.
5. When talking about loop devices, I talk only about Linux rather than Unix in general because loop devices aren't portable between Unix type systems. There are similar mechanisms in macOS, BSD, etc., but the syntax [varies somewhat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device#Availability).
6. Back in the days when disk drives were the size of washing machines and cost more than the department head's luxury car, big computer labs would share a larger proportion of their collective disk space as compared to modern computing environments. The ability to transparently graft a remote disk into the local file system made such distributed systems far easier to use. This is where we get `/usr/share`, for instance.

   Contrast Windows, where drive letters offer you few choices for symbolic expression; does `P:` refer to the "public" space on BigServer or to the "packages" directory on the software mirror server? The UNC alternative requires you to remember which server your remote files are on, which gets difficult in a large organization with hundreds or thousands of file servers.

   Windows didn't get symlinks until 2007, when Vista introduced [NTFS symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link), and they weren't made *usable* [until a decade later](https://onmsft.com/news/better-symlinks-are-coming-in-windows-10-creators-update). Windows' symbolic links are more powerful than Unix's symbolic links — a feature of Unix since [since 1977](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) — in that they can also point to a remote file share, not just to a local path. Unix did that differently, via [NFS in 1984](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System), which builds on top of Unix's preexisting [mount point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(computing)) feature, which it has had since the beginning.

   So, depending on how you look at it, Windows trailed Unix by roughly 2, 3, or 4 decades. You may object, "But it has Unix-style symlinks *now!*" Yet this misses the point, since it means there is no decades-old tradition of *using* them on Windows, so people are unaware of them in a world where Unix systems use them pervasively. It's impossible to use a Unix system for any significant length of time without learning about symlinks.

   It doesn't help that Windows' [`MKLINK` program](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) is [backwards](http://maxi-pedia.com/mklink), and you still can't create them from Windows Explorer, whereas the Unix equivalents to Windows Explorer typically *do* let you create symlinks.
7. Bash chooses the method based on the system's capabilities since `/dev/fd` isn't available everywhere.

Comment: Interestingly, cygwin makes the windows registry available (albeit read-only for now) via a `/proc/registry` pseudo-filesystem on MS Windows.

Comment: `Unix domain sockets are not files` – Well, it depends on [how the file is defined](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690). POSIX definition says "An object that can be written to, or read from, or both. File types include […] socket, […] Other types of files may be supported by the implementation".

Answer (score -2):

Well, being a simplification itself, "Everything is a file" must require a simple characterization.

> When Ken Thompson and Dennis Ritchie started building the UNIX system in 1969, they found a structure that simplified many aspects of the interactions between computers and people. Thompson and Ritchie were aiming to keep their system simple, and they found a collection of primitives that enabled them to do a great deal with a very few primitives.
>
> -- [AT&T Archives: The UNIX Operating System 4:35](https://youtu.be/tc4ROCJYbm0?t=275)

"Everything is a file" as an idea reflects the fact that any user action results in reading or writing bits at addresses controlled by the Operating System. Those are addresses of systems calls, allocated memory and hardware devices. Exposing those addresses via UNIX Shell lets users perform wide range of tasks without additional software.

You interact with the UNIX Shell by either reading, writing, or executing a file, where "file" literally means something you can write, read, or execute. This allows scripts and users interact with machine in exactly the same way, which simplifies certains aspects of interaction.

Windows has no such philosophy. Though it provides equivalent functionality in many cases, it falls short of a principle. For example, Windows Shell is visual. For the end user, each group of tasks tends to have its own toolset, and binding of those toolsets usually requires other toolsets.

Comment: "reading or writing some bits of memory at addresses provided by the OS" -- except that system calls usually work the other way around, by the kernel reading or writing to memory pointed to by the userspace program. Unless of course you include the process memory too, since that's also provided by the OS. Then that would describe literally everything a program does. Either way, I can't see how the thing about accessing memory would be different in a case where e.g. regular files, pipes, sockets and device nodes would all need different system calls to access them.

Comment: What I wrote holds. But allocation details is exactly what UNIX aimed to abstract away with such notions. In case those calls varied, Shell abstraction would not hold.

Comment: ok, what exactly do you mean concretely with "whatever user does to the system, it results in reading or writing some bits of memory at addresses provided by the Operating System"?

Comment: Mainly that "Exposing those bits directly via UNIX Shell enables users to perform wide range of tasks without any additional software". What problems do you have with that?

Comment: I was trying to ask which bits those would be, in the concrete. As in, take e.g. the case of a process reading a file: what bits or memory provided by the OS does it access? And how would that be different if everything _wasn't_ a file? The question specifically mentions comparing to e.g. Windows, where presumably the "everything is a file" doesn't hold.

Comment: Right now, the answer here reads general enough that it's hard to say it's not right, but I'm having a hard time getting anything concrete out of it.

Comment: What is unique to unix is the unix shell concept. Edited my answer a bit, to remove the confusion.

Answer (score -4):

If you consider `Linux` as the *English Language*, the `file systems` are the *alphabets* which are basically the foundation blocks for the *English language*.

From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) page of File system,

> In computing, a file system (or filesystem) is used to control how
>   data is stored and retrieved. Without a file system, information
>   placed in a storage area would be one large body of data with no way
>   to tell where one piece of information stops and the next begins.

So in layman terms without the proper language structure for the English language(which is made from alphabets), the human interaction wouldn't produce any meaning. Similarly, without file systems whatever data we have in the underlying storage device will have no real meaning.