# Why every device in Linux is a file or folder ? what are the advantages?

Tags: linux, filesystems, devices

Why every device in Linux is a file or folder ? what are the advantages ? and 
what is the necessity of `/dev/sda1` , `/dev/sda2` or `/dev/sda3` file ? it's size is 0 bytes .and after mounting the hard disk the files are located in `/media` folder . why `/dev/sda1` or such files necessary?

Comment: Welcome to U&L! Folders (directories) are files as well. Apart from that, your question is comprised of multiple questions which makes this too broad to answer. Please ask a single question at a time. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for replaying @heemayl . questions were spinning around my head that's why I posted all the questions at once . if I won't get any good answer then I definitely post the question in parts. thanks again . BTW I am from Bangladesh too

Comment: Great! Nice to see you here :)

Comment: What would the alternative be?

Comment: This is rather broad, but see also e.g. [A layman's explanation for “Everything is a file” — what differs from Windows?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/141016/170373)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to answer the question "Why every device in Linux is a file"  specifically geared towards data storage (as the question takes them as an example). More in-depth answers regarding the POSIX philosophy may be interesting, too.

The base concept here is, that virtually every operation in a computer essentially comes down to moving data around. Data is read, transformed and written. Of course, depending on which hardware is origin of the data read or target of the data written, the real-world outcome is totally different.

Historically, popular devices for data storage (assume a hard-drive) were handled by the SCSI driver. That is why storage is commonly prefixed with `sd`. You then want a logical "software" representation of the individual physical "hardware" device. You just number them, starting with `a`. Concatenated, a hard-drive may be referred to as `sda`.

Now you have a "file" which you can read data from (writing is analogous). If you read the first byte from `/dev/sda`, you will actually read the byte which is actually sitting on the very beginning of that data storage device (block sizes ignored for the sake of simplicity). You can try this yourself by starting `sudo hexdump -C /dev/sda | less`. Of course, most of the content will be gibberish to the naked eye.
However if you interpreted that gibberish so you know where a partition starts and *mount* that partition, a program (the filesystem driver) interprets the data for you and presents a nice tree-like structure with folders and files you can then read data from in return.

Fun fact: This also holds (to varying degrees) for other kinds of devices (character devices) like keyboards and mice (they "produce" data you can read): `sudo hexdump -C /dev/input/mouse0`).
Or the main memory.
Or even the graphics memory (framebuffer): I occasionally enjoy switching to one of the virtual consoles (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and have my graphics card interpret and display random numbers via `sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/fb0 bs=1M count=1`